# Understanding an example of an EXP-SPACE Problem

Tags: space-complexity

I am trying to understand the example given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXPSPACE) of an **EXP-SPACE** time decision problem.

They write :

> An example of an EXPSPACE-complete problem is the problem of
>   recognizing whether two regular expressions represent different
>   languages, where the expressions are limited to four operators: union,
>   concatenation, the Kleene star (zero or more copies of an expression),
>   and squaring (two copies of an expression)

Here is what I understand. Supposing I have some alphabet $\Sigma = \{a,b,c...,z\}$, then a regular expression
is a pattern in order to specify the set of strings that belong to some language.

So for instance if I have two regular expressions, say

$aa+a^{*}+bb^2$ then any string that satisfies this expression is in $L_1$ (language 1),

$abc$         then any string that satisfies this expression is in $L_2$

Why does determining if these languages are the same in the worst case take exponential space. Further what is the size of the input ? I imagine it could be the sum of lengths of the two reg-expressions, but I am not sure.

Edit: If the Kleene star criterion is dropped, then I could see that we could simply create a set with all possible strings (the power set), and then compare the two sets, not sure about the input size however.

Comment: Why is this problem EXPSPACE-hard? This requires a proof. Perhaps Wikipedia has a link to one.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus right, and here it is: http://people.csail.mit.edu/meyer/rsq.pdf, I will read this and try and give a sketch in the next few days or so.